# How can I create oEmbed support for indavideo in wordpress comments?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, oembed, video-embedding

I heard a plugin, which name is [oEmbed in Comments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/oembed-in-comments/).
(This plugin expand the video links and turn to iframe-player format, like facebook)
The problem is, the plugin dosen't support the [Indavideo storeage](http://indavideo.hu/)
How can I expand this plugin support?
Can anyone point out an example?

Comment: Please, check your Indavideo link...

Comment: Oh!
You're right, fixed, thx!

Comment: See [add oembed provider](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/112200/12615). Looking at Indavideo source code, they support oEmbed discovery: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://indavideo.hu/oembed/ETC...`. Get in touch with them to find the API address and join the pieces. Good luck!

Comment: This just a litle pice of puzzle.
How can I get the link from comment form?
So must be add an id for script or something right?

Comment: Unfortunately,embed,ly dosen't support the indavideo, please look at this example:
http://embed.ly/embed/demos/comments
Paste a link and you can see, embed.ly get an image from indavideo site, but dosen embed the video...

Comment: As I said, I think you need to contact Indavideo, everything depends on them having an API address. After that, try to [edit] your question consolidating all the research.

Comment: Unfortunately indavideo dosten't reply my email in 3 day...